# How to place a Custom Button on list view (Lightning)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, list-view, quickaction

I have created a `Lightning Quick Action` with a custom aura component to do some async processing over all records.
But I cannot find a way to place that button on `List View` in lightning. I have read other SE articles but that seems few years old. So not sure if it is still not possible.

I know that Custom Button shows up, but then I have to wrap this up in VFpage or create a VF page remote action completely.

Is there a way to display the `Action` on list view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, you still have to use a Visualforce page with standard list controller and pass the records to the aura component using lightning out, as explained in [Custom List view buttons in the lightning environment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179402/custom-list-view-buttons-in-the-lightning-environment) - this feature request is on the roadmap, but I don't know when it will be delivered.

Here you have a [sample implementation](https://github.com/Candyvf/vf_listview_lc/tree/main) of how to do it.

Comment: I believe this `Spring 21 you can use LWC in your actions` still wont have any effect on List view buttons, it would just be as same as its working for now with Aura.

Comment: Yes, you still have to use a visualforce page, but it's better to use lightning out with LWC than with Aura, hope that makes sense

Comment: That we can still use right? As the wrapper in both places are VF Page and VF pages can be used to create List view buttons

Comment: Sorry, now I know what you mean. You can't really use a lightning action with lwc - I messed it up. The options are: 1) vf page with standard list controller for list button + lightning out + aura 2)  vf page with standard list controller for list button + lightning out + lwc - Edited the response!

Comment: @NagendraSingh I know a person who implemented this, and she's kindly shared the code - I've added it to the response. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for that, but I dont see the `VF_QuickActionWith_LC` page which is mentioned there.

Comment: I actually need to check that code, as when I try to implement it and when I click the button it does to unkown page.

Comment: I would go ahead and accept this as answer, as its a limitation from salesforce end that no modal can be opened from a List View button.

Comment: @AlbaRivas have you considered using redirect to a isUrlAddressable component instead?

Comment: Ok tried it myself and redirect works pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

As another option, you could create a [screen Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow.htm) and put your aura component there. Then, use the URL of the flow as a URL button.

You'll want to add the `lightning:availableForFlowScreens` interface and handle ending the flow using [availableActions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_navigate_actions.htm) attribute lists.

To get the selected records, there's a [couple](https://www.xbaf.com/flow-list-buttons) [documents](https://wiki.sfxd.org/books/cool-links-stuff/page/how-to-check-off-records-on-a-list-view-and-pass-them-all-to-a-flow-%28button%29) noting the ability to create a collection variable called `ids` that will store all the record Ids. *I do not believe this is officially documented, however.*

Unfortunately, like the VF way, this will open a new tab always so you'll have to handle navigating back to the list view if that's your desired behavior.

Comment: Good alternative! I hadn't thought about it. Question: can you pass the selected records to the screen flow somehow? - Not an expert in flow.

Comment: I definitely mistook the question about related lists vs. list views. I updated it a little. There's a couple documents [here](https://bigassforce.com/flow-list-buttons) and [here](https://wiki.sfxd.org/books/cool-links-stuff/page/how-to-check-off-records-on-a-list-view-and-pass-them-all-to-a-flow-%28button%29) utilizing a collection variable called `ids` that stores all the selected records. I would note that this isn't officially documented as a parameter/feature as far as I'm aware even though it does work

Comment: I'll try it out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with third way - redirect from Visualforce to `lightning:isUrlAddressable` aura component, see [gist here](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/d02eda4d64ae5ad93d254e734a1f1f3b) or:

```
public with sharing class ModalList {
    ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
    public PageReference init() {
        List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
        for (SObject i : this.setCon.getSelected()) {
            ids.add((String)i.get('Id'));
        }
        return new PageReference(
                String.format('/lightning/cmp/c__ModalWrapper?c__ids={0}&c__returnUrl={1}', new String[]{
                        String.join(ids, ','),
                        this.setCon.cancel().getUrl()
                })
        );
    }
    public ModalList(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        this.setCon = controller;
    }
}
```

```
<apex:page
        showHeader="false"
        standardStylesheets="false"
        title="Redirecting"
        standardController="hed__Course_Enrollment__c"
        recordSetVar="leads"
        extensions="PandadocModalList"
        cache="false"
        action="{!init}" />
```

p.s. you could hack and build base64 encoded link to navigateToComponent event which can open lwc components directly

Answer (score 0):

Alba Rivas mentioned the possibility to use Visualforce, Aura Lightning Out app and LWC in the comments. This demonstrates it:

1. Create Visualforce with its Controller:

```apex
public with sharing class ListViewButtonContainerController {
    
    public String selectedIds {get; set;}

    public ListViewButtonContainerController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        List<Foo__c> selectedSObjects = (List<Foo__c>) controller.getSelected();
        Set<Id> ids = new Map<Id, Foo__c>(selectedSObjects).keySet();
        selectedIds = String.join(ids, ',');
    }
}
```

```html
<apex:page standardController="Foo__c" recordSetVar="foos" extensions="ListViewButtonContainerController" lightningStylesheets="true"
standardstylesheets="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="location" />
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:ListViewButtonContainer", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
            "c:listViewButton",
            { "selectedList": '{!selectedIds}' },
            "location",
            function() {});
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

2. Create Lightning Out app `ListViewButtonContainer` in Aura - three lines of markup:

```html
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:dependency resource="listViewButton" />
</aura:application>
```

3. Create a LWC `listViewButton` without targets, just Javascript and markup:

```html
<template>
    {selectedList}
</template>
```

```javascript
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ListViewButton extends LightningElement {

    _selectedList;
    
    @api 
    get selectedList() { return this._selectedList; }

    set selectedList(value) { this._selectedList = value; }
}
```

This lists the IDs of selected Foo's on a new page.